# Get coefficients of a polynomial in Sympy where the expression contains a big O term

Tags: python, sympy

I have a series expansion in Sympy which contains a big O term e.g.

```
x = sp.Symbol("x")
expr = 1/x + 2*x + 3*x**(3/2) + 4*x**2 + sp.O(x**3)
```

And I wish to obtain the coefficients of the powers of `x` as a dictionary

```
{-1: 1, 1: 2, 1.5: 3, 2: 4}
```

Other posts on stackoverflow suggest something like `sp.Poly(expr, x).coeffs()` and converting it into a dictionary. However the `Poly` function raises errors due to the `1/x`, `x**(3/2)` and `sp.O(x**3)` terms.

Comment: `[e.as_coeff_exponent(x) for e in expr.as_ordered_terms()]` may be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed in the comment:

```py
{v[1]: v[0] for v in [e.as_coeff_exponent(x) for e in expr.removeO().as_ordered_terms()]}
# out: {3/2: 3, 2: 4, 1: 2, -1: 1}
```

Note the use of `removeO()`.